# How can vscode display "return value" in terminal?

Tags: c++

```cpp
TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(0);
int i = root->left->val; //root->left is nullptr, so no root->left->val
cout<<i;
```

The code above is wrong. I want my vscode to dispaly "`Process exited after 0.7621 seconds with return value 3221225477"` to let me find out the mistake immediately. But my vscode return nothing like this:

```
PS C:\Users\ValiantHeart\OneDrive\CodeFiles\CFiles> cd "c:\Users\ValiantHeart\OneDrive\CodeFiles\CFiles\" ; if ($?) { g++ 1.cpp -o ./build/1 } ; if ($?) { ./build/.\1 }
PS C:\Users\ValiantHeart\OneDrive\CodeFiles\CFiles>
```

Comment: `exit(num)` will make the program return the given `num` as return value.

Comment: As another approach: writing automated tests (e.g. unit tests) is a good way to check your code is or is not doing what you expect.

Comment: You code is dereferencing a nullptr. So it is not valid code (undefined behavior). So it can generate any exit code it wants.

Comment: After the first line, add `if (root->left == nullptr) std::exit(3221225477);`